# I want to send the meeting invite using angularjs. But facing some issues

Tags: angularjs, outlook-restapi

I am using the rest api of outlook for sending the request. But when i am calling this with above code, in console i am getting error

> unhandled exception

[image]

```
    $scope.createEvents = function(){
        alert("here");
        var url = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Calendars";
        $scope.token = "AQABAAIAAADX8GCi6Js6SK82TsD2Pb7rFu9WBTIi5a6r4Up0vk8NCmPR719K3Uiz7NPUBoT9RwewzSWjPfUIybYn9fVVF2dhQ8b0ObN3oIv5Tq91GwZiTuyBhWZ_s07uDJpCUh40K4Bn2F5eEP9TAp8-5eMY0hfyXb4vIukQwTAe9yXCG75WUS08M7m-_kFbtx-TVq-Y2-SKh8Ut7-v4UQq4NYhlf5LQC1arNbwAZVndfND1vSNGcs1BVJboWd7bcgohHecaR57cAuFav2vfsVEm8n3_IKnlapHzWsyXOw7gXnxTmH2pkfAie0LCiQv8C8nQRnYnLquaWKg6b_ZzTl4ela0EwC9cN74BVMQHFWm6NY1EVM8s-HYevrT8R-WwkAUJXprP40Jp-weLY4-K7vOGk0N0n6fQIeu_WoORIZ18-oKxda6j4XunmrLbWEapQy-Oms9BIAs-AZIVN6Ph1zxQk3CC1bbGK6QkiiL4c2Sgrx_6YoxZt1cMh36pjhbe_TxpC2alk5zJineTK0AZUdGJQWGoy-9fTwtzTbYiaRaV4rispV-q-yiYzpWQ1UWROIPZ5qDq2jlCV7ovTDCWhNd_JgKzzHf-2wANBun9WcX924UVcLkkfvh6XU-QxCo1N6gfGYGUwNNJA1kTZjSyxgKSOAKGxKXz96r5qbtJp34Ci9lEO-PpSeLAL5gHoUOX_PlbM_FO4mLcNEu_fB0Us-5sbV8pKPU-WnfLq3PI8gK3lCi5D_itjesuex1f-o1d1vJ3M4jvx-sgAA";

        var add_events = {
              "Subject": "Discuss the Calendar REST API",
              "Body": {
                "ContentType": "HTML",
                "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
              },
              "Start": {
                  "DateTime": "2016-10-10T18:00:00",
                  "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
              },
              "End": {
                  "DateTime": "2016-10-10T19:00:00",
                  "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
              },
              "Attendees": [
                {
                  "EmailAddress": {
                    "Address": "nishanth.singh@subex.com",
                    "Name": "Nishanth Kumar Singh"
                  },
                  "Type": "Required"
                }
              ]
            };
    $http({
        method: 'JSOPN',
        url: url,
        headers:{
            'Authorization':'Bearer '+$scope.token,
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
        },
        data: add_events
    }).Succes(function (response) {
        alert("Saved")
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of console

Comment: https://imageshack.com/a/img923/3316/06WIOb.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
}).Succes(function (response) {
```

with

```
}).success(function (response) {
```

You have used **upper case** `Success` in your code & the *spelling is incorrect* as well. Let me know once you made this change.

Try to use `.then()` rather than `success()` as `success()` has been deprecated.

#### Update 1

Since you are using version `1.6`, use `.then()`. `success()` is deprecated as I said

```
 $http({
    method: 'JSOPN',
    url: url,
    headers:{
        'Authorization':'Bearer '+$scope.token,
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
    },
    data: add_events
}).then(function (response) {
    alert("Saved")
});
```

---

#### Update 2

You are now facing **[CORS](https://www.maxcdn.com/one/visual-glossary/cors/)** issue. for quick fix try [chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en).

Get proper header to complete the request or you need to config the server to handle such requests.

Comment: @NishantSingh : fixed the link of plugin, you can search on google as well

Comment: This is the new issue i am facing after solving all the CORS issue.

Comment: @NishantSingh Are you sure you are using correct url ? Its showing `404` status code. Also, do you need `JSONP` or `JSON` ?

Answer (score 0):

change method: **'JSOPN'** to
 method: **'JSON'**